# Create read-only repo from remote repo and update it regularly

Tags: svn

I want to create a local copy of a remote repo. This shall be done, because we are running some tools which are using the repo very often and we want to prevent wasting bandwidth.
There are no writing processes on the local copy. It should be updated before the tools are being started.

My first idea was to use `svnsync`, but we can't use it. I read some tutorials about it and it needs a configuration on master side. On the one side it is not possible to do that on the other side there is no possibility to allow incoming transmissions. The master triggers the sync of the slave if I am right
`svnadmin hotcopy` works only on file base.

It is not possible to switch to git, because I am using statsvn for some statistics.

The remote repo is reachable over HTTPS. Is there any possibility to create a copy of it?

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: `... use svnsync, but we can't use it caused of our network security.`  - Please elaborate?

Comment: BTW, have you considered switching over to GIT, and using [git-svn](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-svn.html)?  That gives you a full copy of the repo locally.

Comment: I justed added some details.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I made a mistake. I missunderstood the output of svnsync:

```
svnsync: Repository has not been enabled to accept revision propchanges;
ask the administrator to create a pre-revprop-change hook
```

I thought I have to create such script on master side, not on slave side.
Now I got it working. Just followed the steps:

1. Create slave repo
2. Create pre-revprop-change hook
3. Use `svnsync init` to initialize it
4. Use `svnsync sync` to synchronize it

Thanks to @Zoredache for his comment.

The update is now performed with a daily cronjob.